# Debian: Some packages could not be installed

Tags: linux, debian

I issued the command:

```
apt-get install tor
```

and I got the following result:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tor : Depends: libevent-2.0-5 (>= 2.0.10-stable) but it is not installable
       Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

Could someone explain why this happened? I'm new to Linux.

Comment: I'm using the following command: apt-get install tor

Comment: **Fixed it this way:**

I added the following code to *etc/apt/sources.list*:

    deb     http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org <DISTRIBUTION> main
*DISTRIBUTION = Your distribution name!*

To get your distribution name, use this:

    lsb_release -c

After adding it, I could run it without errors!

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it so the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure that you don't have any 3rd party repositories in your **/etc/apt/source.list** file and inside **/etc/apt/sources.list.d** directory. If so, comment them out.
2. Run **apt-get update** and **apt-get upgrade** commands.
3. Run **apt-get autoremove** and **apt-get -f install** commands.

Hope that the above helps.

Comment: shouldn't `source.list` be pluralised: `sources.list`?